# Continuity of integral of norm of Jacobian matrix

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I have a question about a step in the proof of Theorem 1 of Section 2.8 of Sontag, Mathematical Control Theory (a pdf is available from the author [here](https://www.math.rutgers.edu/~sontag/mct.html)). The statement of the theorem can be found in page 57, but my problem is in the last part of the proof, in page 60. There we have a function  $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ which is of class $C^1$ and of compact support. The author writes (subscripts indicate partial Jacobians)
$$
f(x + a, u + b) - f(x, u) - f_x(x, u)a - f_u(x, u)b = N(x, u, a, b)
$$
where
$$
N(x, u, a, b) = \int_0^1{[(f_x(x+ta, u+tb) - f_x(x, u))a + (f_u(x+ta, u+tb) - f_u(x, u))b]dt}.
$$
In particular, N is jointly continuous in its arguments and thus uniformly continuous since it has compact support. I have no problem understanding this. What escapes me is what is claimed next, that the function $C$ defined by
$$
C(a, b) = \sup_{(x, u) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m} \int_0^1{|f_x(x+ta, u+tb) - f_x(x, u)| + |f_u(x+ta, u+tb) - f_u(x, u)| dt}
$$
is continuous. Here $|\cdot|$ denotes the matrix norm induced from the appropriate Euclidian norms. I am having a hard time filling in the missing steps; I can see that the supremum over $(x,u)$ of $N$ is continuous, but cannot figure out how to translate that to continuity of $C$.